# PyQt get value from GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

I've built an User Interface using `QtDesigner` and then converted the `.ui` to `.py`. The User Interface has different `comboBox` and `textBox` from which I want to read the values once the Run button is clicked. Run a function and then populate other text boxes of the user interface once the calculations are completed. However when I change the value of the `comboBox` and click the button the script still reads the initial value.

I did a simple GUI with a comboBox with two items and a textBox. I'm trying to read the the comboBox text and based on the selected item set the text of the textBox.

Here is the code I'm using to run the `GUI` and read the value:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from pyQt4 import QtCore
import sys
import GUI

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def run(self):
        self.gui = Window()
        name = self.gui.gui_Name.currentText()
        print (name)

        if name == 'Cristina':
            country = 'Italy'
        else:
            country = 'Other'

        self.updated.emit(str(1))


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, GUI.Home):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._thread = MyThread(self)
        self._thread.updated.connect(self.updateText)
        self.update()
        self.
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._thread.start)


    def updateText(self,text):
        self.Country.setText(str(country))
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think is a better way without modifying the .py generated from the .ui?

Comment: That's just a sample that explain the issue but the full task will take a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code that you implement in the run is the one that I think you are abusing the threads since with the `currentTextChanged` signal it would be enough as I show below:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, GUI.Home):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.gui_Name.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onCurrentTextChanged)

    def onCurrentTextChanged(self, text):
        if if name == 'Cristina':
            country = 'Italy'
        else:
            country = 'Other'
        self.Country.setText(str(country))
```

On the other hand if the real code is a time-consuming task then the use of the threads is adequate. If the task takes as reference the value of the `QComboBox` at the moment of pressing the button then it establishes that value as property of the thread, in your case you are creating a new GUI in another thread instead of using the existing GUI:

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        name = self.currentText
        print(name)
        if name == 'Cristina':
            country = 'Italy'
        else:
            country = 'Other'
        self.updated.emit(country)

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, GUI.Home):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._thread = MyThread(self)
        self._thread.updated.connect(self.Country.setText)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)

    def start_thread(self):
        self._thread.currentText = self.gui_Name.currentText()
        self._thread.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It update the country variable however when I pass the value to updateText() I get: Name Error: global name 'Country' is not defined. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've modified self.updated.emit(country) to self.updated.emit(str(country)) and it works now. Thanks for your help

Comment: I will sure do.